# Shell Script not executing, added to crontab

Tags: linux, cron

Here is my shell script, `myscript.sh` located in `~/bin`

```
cd ../environment
. env/bin/activate
python3 office.py
```

The script `office.py` updates the database.  I've tested and works with no issue.  I used this command `./myscript.sh`

Here is cronjob  `*/5 * * * * cd ~/bin/myscript.sh` added to crontab -e

When i check database, no changes.  The cronjob isn't running?  How do i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not running the script but just trying to change directories, which will fail as `myscript.sh` is not a directory. You need to first `cd ~/bin` as you are using relative paths in your script and then run the script. Use this line:

```
*/5 * * * * cd ~/bin && ./myscript.sh
```

Also you may wanna check the syslog to check for cronjobs.

```sh
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Have a look at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log) for more information on logging cronjobs.

Comment: thanks, i tried this but the script isn't running?  In the logs it says `No MTA installed, discarding output`

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake myself. Fixed it now. You have to use `./myscript.sh` of course. The error you are getting is related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/804289). Also have a look at the logging and redirecting output options suggested there. A simple way to check if it has run could also be just appending `&& touch jobrun.txt` to your command. Then if the job was executed you will find the file `jobrun.txt`in `/environment`.